# Map Json to object from json array

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-boot, client

I've just started new project.

My backend client is fetching json from external API, wrap it to right model and then frontend can fetch this transformed data.

My problem is that I am receivig this format of json:

```
 {
"page": 1,
"total_results": 52,
"total_pages": 3,
"results": [
    {
     {Movie1 data}
     {Movie2 data}
     {Movie3 data}
     ...
     }
  ]
 }
```

I would like to fetch only Movies data, so I created Movie model, but it cannot deserialize it.

Here is my code:

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    String resourceURL = url;
    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<Movie[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL,  HttpMethod.GET, entity, Movie[].class);
    if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        for (Movie movie : response.getBody()) {
            System.out.println(movie.originalTitle);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

How I could fetch data from results array? 
Greetnigs Bartek

Comment: you need to create a pojo matching your json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a pojo matching your json. Currently, you are trying to match your json to Movie[], which is not correct.
Try this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class MovieResult {
    List<Movie> results;
    //Getters and Setters
}

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class Movie {
//Getters and Setters   
}



 ResponseEntity<MovieResult> response = restTemplate.exchange(resourceURL,  HttpMethod.GET, entity, MovieResult.class);
 MovieResult movieResult = response.getBody();
 List<Movie> movies = movieresult.getResults();
```

Comment: Thank you, that's solved my problem! Maybe you know any pattern which I should use in my app which I described in main post? My main problem is to transfer this data which I fetched (thanks to you) to Rest controller.

Comment: I think you should use object mapper to transfer that data directly to bean